Can ので be conceptualized as nominalizing an idea with the の particle, and then making use of that idea with the で particle?
When ので is used as 'because of; given that; since', what is truly happening with this grammar point? Is a sentence is being nominalized with の, and then that noun is being made use of in the situation that follows, so で is then used?
教科書がないので、一緒に見てもいいですか？
Normal Translation: Can we look at a textbook together since I don’t have one?
Conceptualized as の+で: I don't have a textbook, using that situation, can we look at it together?
I am aware translations with this concept do not make sense in English but I want to understand if this is how it is thought to in Japanese or does the ので used in this grammar point have nothing to do with the particles の and で? I have not found it mentioned anywhere that this is the case but I can understand that it would confuse learners if this grammar point was presented this way.

This で is the て form of だ, making it the て form of のだ, which is, like you said, nominalizing a sentence, but in this case, の, or もの, (It is that...) represents a reason. Also, since you seem new to Japanese, just in case you don't know, verbs aand adjectives can be connected in other ways like the masu stem
(蘇り、読み) and the, "adverb", form (軽く、難く、固く), although it may be a little more formal or literary. However, I am not that experienced in Japanese and have no knack to properly know why もの can represent such.

Wow, it is just んです/のだ + て form. I have not seen it presented in textbooks or online like that before. I do find most beginner to intermediate source just explain what something means but not why, which the 'why' is the most helpful part for me. Thank you.


Is a sentence is being nominalized with の, and then that noun is being made use of in the situation that follows, so で is then used?

Yes, yes that's exactly what's happening in the sentence. Proof? Just like the nominalizing の, when it is preceded by nouns 名詞 and な-adjectives 形容動詞, it must have a な

俺は面接なんて苦手ので、… ❌
そいつは学生ので、… ❌


俺は面接なんて苦手なので、… ⭕️
そいつは学生なので、… ⭕️

And as @Star Peep has mentioned, idea about で being the te-form of だ is also correct, and the linguistic logic behind it has already been well explained!
The same の being the nominalized applies to のに too which is used for contrast.

Hey... I thought I was the one who mentioned that で was the て-form of だ.

（´>人<｀）　I'm so sorry my brain must be confused with all the info when I wrote this answer, will edit now !
